# What is the purpose of two forward slashes in xslt? "//"

Tags: xml, xslt

I am in an XML class and have the following line of code..

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//@qty)" />
```

What is the purpose of the "//" before the qty attribute? What does it designate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `//` is the equivalent of the `descendant::` axis, so it will return all of the @qty values that are descendants of the context node. i.e.: in this case no context is given so it should return all values for the document.

If you had `.//` then the context would be the current node, and the output would be all descendants from that node, instead of the document.

**Update** As David correctly points out these two expressions are not strictly equivalent, just functionally equivalent for your question. He notes the subtleties below. However, I think you will discover that although technically `//` does equate to `descendant-or-self::node()`:

```
//x == //descendant-or-self::node()/x
```

it makes sense to expect `descendant::` when using `//` because:

```
<x/>//* => ()
<x/>/descendant-or-self::* => <x/>
```

and you cannot simply use `//` without something to select. So there is no situation where `//` can actually give you the `-or-self` part.

```
/a/b// => {error}
```

Comment: So it would select a count of ALL descendant @qty from the root?

Comment: equating `//` with `descendant::` isn't strictly accurate.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good point. I updated the answer with some clarification.

Answer (score 4):

`//`  is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`

although in some expressions it acts similarly to descendant:: it is not the same. For example in the expression in the question

```
descendant::@qty
```

would be a syntax error as you can't have both the descendant and attribute axis in a single step.

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/@qty
```

on the other hand is a legal expression.

The other notable difference is `//*[1]` which selects every element that is the first child of its parent. whereas `/descendant::*[1]` selects the first element in the document.

Answer (score 1):

`//` is a "macro" which expands to

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/
```

including the slashes. In other words `foo//bar` is exactly the same xpath expression as `foo/descendant-or-self::node()/bar`, and selects all `bar` elements that are descendants of any `foo` element child of the current node (because `x/descendant-or-self::node()` includes `x` itself - that's the `or-self` bit).